# Replace with sed ; and whitespaces

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, command, spaces

i need to replace with sed command this lines:

```
;[homes]
;   browseable = no
```

In this lines:

```
[homes]
browseable = yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to fix the two lines shown.  It gets a little trickier if you consider that this is ini-file format and there could be other sections which contain `browseable` and other sections than `[homes]` which should not be edited.

```
sed -e '/^;\[homes]/,/^;*\[/{
        s/;\[homes]/[homes]/
        s/^; *browseable.*/browseable = yes/
        }'
```

Given the input file:

```
;[alerts]
;  browseable = no
;[homes]
;  browseable = no
;  alternatives = no
;[houses]
;  browseable = no
[mezzanine]
;  browseable = no
   alternatives = yes
```

The output from the above script is:

```
;[alerts]
;  browseable = no
[homes]
browseable = yes
;  alternatives = no
;[houses]
;  browseable = no
[mezzanine]
;  browseable = no
   alternatives = yes
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed -e 's/^; *//'`, unless your example doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: You miss the `no` `yes` change.

Comment: Right.  Must have been because of the question title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do the changes.

```
awk '{sub(/^;[ ]*/,"")} /browseable/ {$3="yes"}1'
[homes]
browseable = yes
```

---

Given data from Jonthan

```
awk '/homes/ {sub(/^;[ ]*/,"");f=1} f && /browseable/ {sub(/^;[ ]*/,"");$3="yes";f=0}1' file
;[alerts]
;  browseable = no
[homes]
browseable = yes
;  alternatives = no
;[houses]
;  browseable = no
[mezzanine]
;  browseable = no
   alternatives = yes
```

Or like this:

```
awk '/homes/ {$0="[homes]";f=1} f && /browseable/ {$0="browseable = yes";f=0}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work,

```
sed 's/^;//g;s/^ *\(.*\)/\1/g;s/no/yes/g' file
```

Comment: i just answered what op is asked. Otherwise Jonathan's answer is the best.